Add HTTP Headers to Lighting App Page
I am trying to embed a Lightning App Page outside Salesforce and where I am embedding it requires the app page when requested to include the necessary HTTP headers in the response to the page.
One of the headers thats required is "Referrer-Policy" and so I enabled "Include Referrer-Policy HTTP header" from "Session Settings".
But I still don't see the header being available in the response when the page is requested.
Is there any other way to add the http headers to the Lightning App Page?
I am trying to add an LWC to my Lightning App Page which then I am planning to embed outside salesforce so that when the page loads it takes user to the salesforce login screen and after successfully logging in will show the lightning app page with the component in it. I am also reading about Lightning Out or Aura or visualforce page.
